# On the equality of sum of areas of "sector-like" regions

Tags: geometry, contest-math, euclidean-geometry, circles, alternative-proof

The problem:

> Suppose $AB, CD, EF, GH$ are four equally inclined (angle of $45^\circ$) chords of a circle concurrent at an interior point $P$ of the circle, dividing the circle into 8 parts. Show that the sum of the areas of sector-like regions $HPA, CPE, GPB, DPF$ is equal to the sum of the areas of the remaining regions $APC, EPG, BPD, FPH$.

Figure: 
[image]

My solution:
We use the area of curve from point $P$, and denote the distance $PX$ by $r(\theta)$ if $\angle XPA = \theta$ and $X$ lies on the circle. Then,

$$\begin{align}2(\mathrm{Ar}(APC)+\mathrm{Ar}(EPG)+\mathrm{Ar}(BPD)+\mathrm{Ar}(FPH)) &= \int_0^{\pi/4} r(\theta)^2 \mathrm d\theta + \int_{\pi/2}^{3\pi/4} r(\theta)^2 \mathrm d\theta + \int_{\pi}^{5\pi/4} r(\theta)^2 \mathrm d\theta + \int_{3\pi/2}^{7\pi/4} r(\theta)^2 \mathrm d\theta \\
&= \int_0^{\pi/4} r(\theta)^2 + r(\theta + \pi/2)^2+ r(\theta + \pi)^2 + r(\theta+3\pi/2)^2 \mathrm d\theta \\
&= \int_0^{\pi/4} 4R^2 \mathrm d\theta \\
&= \pi R^2
\end{align}$$
where $R$ is the radius of the circle, and the second-last equality uses [Archimedes' 11th proposition](https://www.cut-the-knot.org/Curriculum/Geometry/BookOfLemmas/BOL11.shtml).

**Question:**
This problem comes from an olympiad book, and the book has nowhere mentioned integrals (not even derivatives), or used calculus, so I feel there should be an alternate and more elementary approach. How should I go about solving this without calculus? Also, I don't think the book intended a dissection approach. Probably standard Euclidean or co-ordinate geometry only.

Comment: See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1828449/the-grey-area-is-equal-to-the-white-area?rq=1) on how to prove the pizza theorem by dissection.

Comment: I don't trust visual proofs much @DarkLordOfPhysics . Is there a standard procedure to dissect the circle, that works howsoever $P$ is placed in the circle?

Comment: There is an explicit procedure for constructing a variant dissection presented in [this journal](https://www.jstor.org/stable/10.4169/math.mag.85.1.26?read-now=1&seq=3#page_scan_tab_contents) if that is helpful.

Comment: @DarkLordOfPhysics I don't have access. However, I don't think the book intended a dissection proof too.

Comment: The original solution to the problem given by Michael Goldberg derives Archimedes' 11th proposition but then seemingly jumps to 

>Hence, for any rotation of the two chords through the angle $\phi$, the area swept out is $4r^2 \phi /2$. If $\phi = \pi /4$, the area is $\pi r^2/2$.

This is very suggestive of using the polar differential area element. It may be possible to argue that the swept area should be proportional to $\phi$ by iteratively partitioning each quasi sector in half $n$ times and then noting that the full circle would be swept out with $\phi=\pi/2^{n+1}$.

Comment: @DarkLordOfPhysics but to make that argument rigorous, you will need limits, no?

Comment: Yes, you are right. I do not know of a rigorous proof without invoking calculus or referring back to a dissection. I suppose that my argument would only show that the swept area being linear in $\phi$ would be consistent.